# Failed to load Twig template "_includes/field", index "764771142": cache is corrupted

Tags: cache

Making first steps with Craft CMS, and it's great, but there is one thing i can't figure out:

When trying to add a new entry with a rather complex set of fields (including matrix) there is an error:

> Failed to load Twig template "_includes/field", index "764771142": cache is corrupted.
>
> in E:\craft\playground\vendor\craftcms\cms\src\templates_includes\field.html
> line 17:

```
{% if instructions or input %}
    {% embed "_includes/forms/field" with {
        label: field.name|t('site')|e,
        translatable: translatable,
        siteId: siteId,
        required: (not static ? required : false),
```

Editing existing entries works fine.

Running 3.0.4

Clear Cache Tool has run, and i also delete the cache files in `/storage`. No custom field types.

Thanks for ideas.

Comment: Additional info: This error occurs only when devMode=true

Comment: Restricting image upload to a single folder {owner.filmtitle|kebab} possibly caused the error, replacing the folder template helped: {% if owner.filmtitle %}{owner.filmtitle|kebab}{%else%}default{%endif%}

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, Susi.  Would you mind adding that as an official answer in case it ends up helping someone in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additional info: This error occurs only when devMode=true

Restricting image upload to a single folder `{owner.filmtitle|kebab}` possibly caused the error, replacing the folder template helped:

```
{% if owner.filmtitle %}{owner.filmtitle|kebab}{%else%}default{%endif%}
```

Nevertheless i don't understand why the former version caused the error, and the error message is very misleading.

Comment: Because every volume has a different layout and you'll receive an exception if the layout does not include a field with the handle `filmtitle`. Disabling dev mode prevents exceptions at all. That's Why you won't notice them

Comment: @RobinSchambach, thanks, but `filmtitle` is  always there and mandatory. I think  the kebab filter causes the error when applied at this point. I tried that in combination with the `''convertFilenamesToAscii' => true` config to create valid folder names. But maybe theres a better solution for that?

Comment: Addition : We didn't want to use the slug, because that looks different for some crazy SEO reasons.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem on the backend. The issue seems to be using dynamic parameters within the directory path. For instance I want all my product images to go into products/{slug}. Without {slug} in the path all is fine. But when I add that parameter I get the error shown by the OP when I try to add a new Commerce product.